# why there is a difference between calling (call) on a method and calling the method on the obj

Tags: javascript, call

sorry I really should of asked why there is a differnce ,

```
`Object.prototype.toString.call(o).slice(x,y);`
```

and this?

```
o.toString().slice(x.y);
```

// why those are different , call should change the 'this' value for the called method 
// and toString is already inherited ,

```
var x = 44 ;


`Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`; //"[object Number]"

x.toString(); // '44'
```

Comment: x,y and x.y?  The first one is passing two arguments to slice and the second is passing the y property on the x object to slice.

Comment: I guess he wanted to write .slice(x,y) in the second example

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) on the method here:

> ```
> Object.prototype.toString(o).slice(x,y);
> ```

Instead, you just call the method (on the prototype object) with `o`  as an argument.

To get an equivalent method to call to

> ```
> o.toString().slice(x.y);
> ```

(which calls the method on the `o` object, with no arguments), you will need to use

```
o.toString.call(o).slice(x.y);
```

---

> Why is `x.toString()` different from `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`?

Because `x = 44` is a number, and when you access `x.toString` you get the [`Number.prototype.toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) not the [`Object.prototype.toString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString). You could also write

```
Number.prototype.toString.call(x)
```

to get `"44"`.

Comment: //sorry I ment to type it ; 
//so
Object.prototype.toString.call(o) //

Comment: //sorry I ment to type it ; 
//so
Object.prototype.toString.call(o) //

Answer (score 0):

Use second one and check the difference between a class (your first case) and an instance of that class (second case).

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29)

Its a general object oriented programming issue common for all languages.

- First is the general definition of the type (without any specific data) - you call it wrong
- The second one is a particular instance with own data (can be multiple)

Anyway:
Object.prototype.toString(o) returns "Object object" so it's not working for you well.

Answer (score 0):

The first one (`Object.prototype.toString`) calls the built in or default toString function for objects, the second calls the toString function of `o`, which may or may not have been overwritten

```
var o = {};
o.toString();
    // "[object Object]"
o.toString = function(){};
o.toString();
    // undefined
Object.prototype.toString.call(o);
    // "[object Object]"
```

With a number, such as 44, the toString function is different from a objects. Calling the toString function of a variable with the value 44, will actually do `Number.prototype.toString.call()`. Hence the different output.

a few different types:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString