# Why does toString() work in two different ways?

Tags: javascript, tostring

I've regularly used toString() for two different ways, but only recently I realized I don't understand the mechanics of what is going on.

For example I use this function to return the type of an object:

```
var getType = function (obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
};

getType([1,2,3]) // returns "Array"
```

But if I do

```
[1,2,3].toString()
```

I will get

```
"1,2,3"
```

I thought that `call` simply calls the function with a given `this` which is equal to `[1,2,3]`.

Similarly I thought that doing `[1,2,3].toString()` calls toString with `[1,2,3]` as the `this` value as well.

In both cases there are no parameters and the `this` value is the same so what is different?

Comment: `[1,2,3].toString !== Object.prototype.toString`. You'd have to call the same function to have those calls be equivalent.

Comment: Yes, but you're calling two different functions.

Comment: I see Array has its own `toString()` function defined which would override the objects `toString()`

Comment: JavaScript has several different data types and most have their own `.toString()` method. This makes sense since the serialization of different types would naturally require a different process.

Comment: related: [why there is a difference between calling (call) on a method and calling the method on the obj](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24529890/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because

```js
Array.prototype.toString !== Object.prototype.toString
```

For example:

```js
Array.prototype.toString.call([1,2,3]);  // "1,2,3"
Object.prototype.toString.call([1,2,3]); // "[object Array]"
```

Comment: @test You need parentheses: `({a:'a'}).toString`. Or `({a:'a'}.toString)`. Or `var o = {a:'a'}; o.toString`

Comment: Thanks, Logically, I would expect to be able to call `{a:'a'}.toString()` just as I would do `[1,2,3].toString()` but this does not work.  The syntax is different for one and for two the output is different.

Comment: @test Because if you start a statement with `{...}`, it's a [block statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1). So you must do something to make it an expression. Adding parentheses does that. Then it's parsed as an [object initialiser](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) instead of like a block.

Comment: @test No, it thinks it's a block. `{a:'b'}` is a [block statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1), `a` is a [label](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.12), and it evaluates `'b'`.

Comment: Prototypical inheritance, you should mention.